# getting error while running java websaop service

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.<clinit>(LifecycleBase.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I was trying to create wsag4j agreement service and I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add apache logging library to your classpath.

You can download the library [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.9) and [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html) you can get instructions on how to add it to classpath.